# prevent duplication code with ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

i have a list of same operation on same list using ramda like below :

```
 size: { sum: R.sum(R.map(R.prop('size'), ordersRep)) },
      price: { sum: R.sum(R.map(R.prop('price'), ordersRep)) },
      profit: { sum: R.sum(R.map(R.prop('profit'), ordersRep)) },
      discount: { sum: R.sum(R.map(R.prop('discount'), ordersRep)) },
```

which i want to define main function : `R.sum(R.map(R.prop('somthing'), ordersRep))` other place and use it wheneve needed. but it's take two argument one list and one prop name. how can i handle it ?

Comment: R.pipe, R.partial

Comment: Well yes, write a function! I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Given `ordersRep` is the same everywhere, why do you want to make it an argument?

Answer (score 3):

```
let combined = (prop, coll) => R.sum(R.pluck(prop, coll))
```

For an arguably more functional version (point-free courtesy of Ross Mackay):

```
let combined = prop => R.compose(R.sum, R.pluck(prop))

let sumPrice = combined('price');
sumPrice([{price: 2}, {price: 3}]); // 5
```

Point-free:

```
let combined = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.sum, R.pluck));
```

Comment: in the functional version where is the array? how to give the list to it?

Comment: I get an error `t` is not a function when running that, but the `partial(map, prop(prop))` can be written as just `pluck(prop)`

Comment: As you mentioned the point-free version doesn't add much, but could be written as `let combined = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.sum, R.pluck))`. It's a bit harder to read, but one benefit is you can give both args or just the prop, whereas the other version needs to be called `combined(prop)(array)`